# JsonResult data return not displayed on a textbox but is displayed on a textarea

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, textbox, textarea, jsonresult

A JsonResult is calling me back an anonymous type. 
I can use the alert function to check it is correctly received client side, but impossible to fill a textbox value with this result. While I can fill a textarea value,
I tried to parse the result (the textbox are bound to my model view, to a float and a int data type, but I don't think its because of this type).

This is my code :

```
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/MyCalledFunction/?arg1=" + $("#FK_ARG").val(),                datatype: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data) {
// my return result if an anymous type 
                        var price = data.price;
                        var NbDefaultDaysNumber = data.NbDefaultDaysNumber;
alert(price);// display the msgbox with '100'
                        $("#MY_PRICE").html(price);// textbox type value -> failed
                        $("#DEFAULT_DAYS").html(NbDefaultDaysNumber); // textbox type value -> failed
                        $("#ANOTHER_AREA").html(NbDefaultDaysNumber);// text area property value... -> works

                    }
                }
            });


        public JsonResult MyCalledFunction(string arg1)
        {
// some unintersting code...
           var myReturnJSon = new {price = 100, 
                            DEFAULT_DAYS = 10};
return Json(myReturnJSon);
        }
```

Im sure it's a stupid question of binding with some text parameters somewhere.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a textbox (by which I assume you mean an `<input>` with `type="text"`, you should be using `val()` and not `html()`

```
$("#DEFAULT_DAYS").val(NbDefaultDaysNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have input in View like this

```
<input type="text" value="" id="MY_PRICE" />
```

then you should use

```
var price = data.price;                          
var NbDefaultDaysNumber = data.NbDefaultDaysNumber;  
alert(price);// display the msgbox with '100'                         
$("#MY_PRICE").val(); // This Display in text box
```

This should be work.